# Simple app does not show in AVD

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am testing out my first actual app, which is super-simple.
(I've already tested out a simple hello world one)
Unfortunately my app does not show in the AVD. I have two classes and my `AndroidManifest.xml` file
My first class, named `CrazyEightActivity.java` has this code,

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CrazyEightsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CrazyEightsView CrazyEightsView = new CrazyEightsView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

My second class named `CrazyEightsView.java` has:

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class CrazyEightsView extends View
{
    private Paint redPaint;
    private int circleX;
    private int circleY;
    private float radius;

public CrazyEightsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        circleX = 100;
        circleY = 100;
        radius = 30;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
    }

}
```

And finally my `.xml` has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crazyeights"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crazyeights.CrazyEightsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm sorry theres so much code, which may make it overwhelming, so thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you try to set the content view before calling `CrazyEightsView`?

Comment: it looks to me like you are setting the content view to an xml but you are making your crazyeightsview and not setting it to the content view, is you crazyeights view in the xml? because you are not setting the content view to crazyeightsview

Answer (score 1):

```
CrazyEightsView CrazyEightsView = new CrazyEightsView(this);


setContentView(CrazyEightsView);
```

You dont seem to have anything in your xml layout! set your activities' view to your custom view

Comment: So I should replace:  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); with setContentView(CrazyEightsView); ?

Comment: Hmm... I tried relaunching the AVD, but it still didn't appear there. Is there anything else I can do? If you want a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtLreFIVnSWS3NKSldBd2NmM1U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't appended your custom view to the `Activity`